# can vncviewer forward alt key to server for application switch?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vncviewer

I'm using the `tightvnc` `vncviewer` to connect to a Windows10 server from my Linux machine running `Ubuntu`. Now I wish had the option to switch between aplications on the Windows machine using alt-tab over vnc. I've found a plethora of articles describing this on the web but they all seem to refer to the vncviewer that's running on Windows and I did not find any info for the Linux version of it. Can anyone help?

I also started a separate thread in the group: comp.os.linux.networking (subject "can vncviewer forward alt key to server for application switch?") -  - I will make sure that answers are synchronized between the two separate threads!

Comment: Is `tightvnc` a hard requirement? This works out of the box with tigervnc's `vncviewer` (while in full-screen mode).

Comment: @Hermann no, I'm just using `tightnc` because that comes with `Ubuntu`. I'll give it a try with *tigervnc*. Thanks! You may want to move this to an answer that I'll happily accept if it works for me, otherwise I'll report back!

Comment: This did workj, yes!  I downloaded the sources from github, compiled, installed and started the new `vncviewer` binary and taskj switching with `ALT-TAB` works just fine now! Excellent, exactly hat I was looking for!  Thank you Herman  oder vielleicht Dankeschön! (Thank you in German - just a guess!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

This works out of the box with [tigervnc](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/releases)'s vncviewer (while in full-screen mode).